# How to get redirector.googlevideo link

Tags: youtube, google-drive-api, jwplayer

i have a problem, becouse i want to use JWplay including a redirector.googlevideo link, but i cant do that.

i need to know how to get a video link like **redirector.googlevideo** for put in **JWplayer**. I have a google drive account, but i don't know how to create a link like: https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id...

I already upload a video in google drive but i don't know how can i resolve this problem

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported by the Drive API per se, as I used [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) to retrieve all the drive metadata but this link could not be found.

However, I found this [Google-Drive-Player-Script](https://github.com/ArdiArtani/Google-Drive-Player-Script) which might help you as it

> "Grabs google drive streaming links
>   (redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?..)"

Check it out.